# How to switch Ventura installer to light mode?

Tags: ventura, macos

Is there a way to switch to light mode *while installing* Ventura? This is when your Mac reboots into something like recovery mode and guides you through the install process.

Some combinations of colours in dark mode (such as that sickly red on grey) are unreadable on my monitor without a color profile, which I can't select until after the install is complete.

Comment: As an aside, red on grey is not a color I believe I saw in the installer when I ran it...

Comment: It's used in Disk Utility on unsafe buttons, like partitioning or erasing partitions. Luckily, by virtue of it being unsafe the button you want is pretty obvious… it's the one you can't read! :)

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood what you're referring to - makes sense. You're talking about the recovery partition?

Comment: Yes, that's a good point for clarification. Fixed it. ;)